# Open a html file using default web browser

Tags: c#, browser

I'm using this to get the path and executable of default web browser:

```
public static string DefaultWebBrowser
        {
            get
            {

                string path = @"\http\shell\open\command";

                using (RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(path))
                {
                    if (reg != null)
                    {
                        string webBrowserPath = reg.GetValue(String.Empty) as string;

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(webBrowserPath))
                        {
                            if (webBrowserPath.First() == '"')
                            {
                                return webBrowserPath.Split('"')[1];
                            }

                            return webBrowserPath.Split(' ')[0];
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

And:

```
 protected static bool Run(string FileName, string Args)
        {
            try
            {
                Process proc = new Process();

                processInfo.FileName = FileName;
                 proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

                if(Args != null) proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Args;

                proc.Start();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            return false;
        }
```

Then I call the web browser: `Run(DefaultWebBrowser, "foo.html")`

The question is: the above function is calling Firefox and IE (the two web browsers installed on my pc) instead of Internet Explorer, the default web browser. I have no idea how to fix this.

**EDIT**

I have downloaded and installed the Google Chrome, set it as default web browser, but oddly the above error don't happens with it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can replace all that code with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToHtmlFile);
```

This will automatically start your default browser, or rather look up the default handler for `.htm` or `.html` files and use that.

Now with Firefox set as default this can sometimes cause weird exceptions (I think if Firefox is starting for first time), so you might want to do a `try/catch` on it to handle that.

Comment: I had tried it. But in some pcs .htm/.html are not opened with a web browser. the .htm/.html extensions can be associated with an text editor or IDE for example.

Comment: Although the default program _can_ be changed, you shouldn't have a problem really. See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816) for some tips on using `ShellExecute` to launch the default web browser, and also the paths for some registry keys (which you're probably already aware of). In the end, the user can most probably intervene by changing some default programs... but you shouldn't worry too much about this, as it's unavoidable to a certain extent.

Comment: As Jack said, this is a terrible idea. I personally have an editor set as default application to open HTML files, and it unnerves me to no end to see programs open their readme file in that editor instead of the default browser. There IS a difference between 'default browser' and 'default app to open HTML with' in Windows.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Does not guarantee that the file will be opened with a browser.

Comment: @Theyouthis feel free to contribute if you have a better solution

Answer (score 26):

UPDATE 30 April 2022: For **.Net Core**  better solution is to set UseShellExecute = true as suggested in [.Net Core 2.0 Process.Start throws "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808315/net-core-2-0-process-start-throws-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appl/47066203#47066203)

Original suggestion:
For **.Net Core** you need to call (suggested in [.Net Core 2.0 Process.Start throws "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808315/net-core-2-0-process-start-throws-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appl/46808516#46808516))

```
 var proc = Process.Start(@"cmd.exe ", @"/c " + pathToHtmlFile);
```

When I tried `Process.Start(pathToHtmlFile);`,
I've got *System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform*.

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47066203/3258851)** would be the preferred way, actually.

Answer (score 8):

In case if you're getting `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` exception, you need to set `UseShellExecute` to `true`

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\path\test.html")
{
    UseShellExecute = true
};
p.Start();
```

See [.Net Core 2.0 Process.Start throws "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808315/net-core-2-0-process-start-throws-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appl/47066203#47066203)

Comment: this is the only one that works for me in .net core 8, others (proc = Process.Start(@"cmd.exe ", @"/c " + pathToHtmlFile); , etc) do not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't have html default association to a browser, use

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Chrome", Uri.EscapeDataString(pathToHtmlFile))`

Comment: It assumes that the user has chrome browser installed.

Comment: The code for DefaultWebBrowser is given at the top of the page

Comment: Back to using that code if you want it more generic (sorry assumed it was obvious).

Comment: Ok, I see your original problem was something funky going on with DefaulWebBrowser. - "_the above function is calling the firefox and IE_".

Comment: Since DefaultWebBrowser returns only a single string, it's hard to see how that is happening. Maybe something to do with the parsing of `reg.GetValue(String.Empty) as string` return value.

Comment: didn't work, even though I have chrome installed (as default)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I used `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToHtmlFile);` :

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.`'

I was able to open the html file in the default browser with this code :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
try
{
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = pathToHtmlFile;
    process.Start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Im using a code, where i look up for exe files first.
For example, if exsists chrome.exe (in its default path) else if exists firefox.exe or launcher.exe (for opera) etc... if doesnt any exists, try to run iexplore.exe with pathToHtmlFile parameter. This is my solution, where i use external config, where a set my browser, doesnt matter what is set default in OS.