# C# Execute Application Using Process.Start() as params to cmd and active RedirectStandardOutput

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am using Visual Studio Clickones and try to execute `(.appref-ms) application`
and using `RedirectStandardOutput`...

I have to use the option `"Prefer 32-bit"` because I am using Access DB with connection string as `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.`

This is my execution code :

```
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\hed-b\Desktop\PulserTester.appref-ms")
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    p.Start();
    reportNumber = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

This is the error I have got

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not
>   a valid application for this OS platform.'

Editing

By look here, I see that I can run it by cmd

[.Net Core 2.0 Process.Start throws "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808315/net-core-2-0-process-start-throws-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appl?rq=1)

as

```
var proc = Process.Start(@"cmd.exe ",@"/c C:\Users\hed-b\Desktop\PulserTester.appref-ms")
```

But How can I use RedirectStandardOutput this way?

Comment: I think you can try this, ' 
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
 info.Arguments = @"/c C:\Users\hed-b\Desktop\PulserTester.appref-ms";
set the info you need with your RedirectStandardOutput and then 'Process process = Process.Start(info)

Comment: You can't, redirecting I/O requires using ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  And that prevents starting an appref-ms file.  As long as you commit to the horror of hard-coding path names, you might as well go whole-hog and hardcode C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe C:\Windows\System32\dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbShortcut,"yourpath.appref-ms".  Not that this likely to work, rundll32.exe is not a console mode app so has nothing to redirect.  ClickOnce is not your favorite deployment technique, unless you use it to deploy both executables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're intending to start CMD and run a command, but your code just tries to run that command as an application.

Try something like this.

```
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe")
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        Arguments = "/c C:\Users\hed-b\Desktop\PulserTester.appref-ms"
    };
    p.Start();
    reportNumber = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

Using the blocking `ReadToEnd` will pause your thread while that code runs and makes it harder to capture error output also - Have a look at this answer for a demonstration of a non blocking solution that captures both standard data and standard err : [ProcessInfo and RedirectStandardOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145969/processinfo-and-redirectstandardoutput)

Comment: Thanks for answer.. I tried it the problem it  this (.appref-ms) file its just the runner of my program (something of visual studio) 
and my real program does not wait on WaitForExit();