# The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform. Selenium.ChromeDriver, StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Tags: .net, selenium, windows-10, selenium-chromedriver, nuget-package

My OS in Windows 10. I am trying to run Selenium project that was working fine around 3 years ago however I am running in the unexpected error message

`The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.`

Steps I have taken so far: Re-ran VS2015 as administrator and got same error, then checked if chromedriver.exe is there in the project directory, it is.
Updated Nuget packages of `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver to 74.0.3729.6`, `Selenium.WebDriver to 3.141`, and `Selenium.Support to 3.141` in vain.

Tried running it from a basic console application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var crawler = new Crawler())
        {
            crawler.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

same error.

After some research I [have found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808315/net-core-2-0-process-start-throws-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appl) that due to some changes in .Net core I need to fire processes differently.

However, I am not in control of running `.exe` directly, this is done internally by ChromeDriver `OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)` and only parameters passed are directory and chrome running options...

Below is stack trace where error originated,

```
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
at WebAnalyzer.Controllers.HomeController.About()
```

I am sure by now someone has managed to run Selenium with new changes.

**How do I run Selenium ChromeDriver so it wouldn't break at creating the process at StartWithCreateProcess ?**

Comment: What is your OS? chromedriver version?

Comment: @Guy Hello Guy, windows 10,  chromedriver version 2.20, selenium webdriver 2.53 added win 10 to tags, thanks for suggestion. I am updating selenium nuget as we speak

Comment: @Guy Updated nugets, still getting same exact error

Comment: chromedriver 2.20 is ancient, update it as well http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. Make sure to match the version with the browser version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a NuGet package that I have used to get chromedriver.exe with

The one that didn't work was

[image]

after replacing it with following chrome got fired

[image]

and everything started working again.