# Process.Start() throws Win32Exception "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"

Tags: c#, .net-core, process, process.start

I'm trying to make my program open a link to a local HTML file in the user's default browser as a quick way to open a help page for my program. From what I gathered, using `Process.Start(path)` was the easiest way to do it, but when calling it, I get an exception "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"

This is the (very quick) code I wrote:

```cs
_helpURL = "HelpPage.html"

private static void OpenHelpPage()
{
    Process.Start(_helpURL);
}
```

However, when the function is called, it throws the following error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (193): An error occurred trying to start process 'Help Page/HelpPage.html' with working directory 'C:\Users\ ...'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
```

The directory definitely contains the file in question and I have Chrome set as my default browser for handling .html files.

I haven't been able to find any answers online about getting this error while opening an HTML file this way.

Comment: Take a look a [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-8.0).

Comment: Have u checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808315/net-core-2-0-process-start-throws-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appl

Comment: @MostafaMohamedAhmed Thank you, I had read it before but I didn't realise it applied in my situation. Used that method and everything works as intended!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! [Used this answer to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808315/net-core-2-0-process-start-throws-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appl), as suggested by @MostafaMohamedAhmed. Thank you very much :3

Here's the code I ended up using: (`_exeUrl` is the location of the executable)

```cs
private static void OpenHelpPage()
{
    Process p = new()
    {
        StartInfo = new(_exeUrl + _helpUrl)
        { UseShellExecute = true }
    };
    p.Start();
}
```