# How open(HTML, ASP.net) page inside project directory by pressing button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to popup internal page (within project folder) when pressing button, I already used the code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.mkf.com");
```

but I need to run internal page like (mk.html), how can I doing this

Comment: `but I need to run internal page` whats an internal page mean? like one in your bin directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a html file using default web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989709/open-a-html-file-using-default-web-browser)

Comment: yes sorry I mean inside directory

Comment: Not Open a html file using default web browser . I need to open page inside project directory this what I mean

Answer (score 0):

you can open the internal page via directory path in your "Process.Start" function.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mk.html");
```

Comment: I already used this, but error message appeared "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'
"

Comment: Have you used the total directory?